# Fire click enter event on html input text

Tags: html, excel, vba, enter

I am trying to fire the event we see when user writes a ticker code in a input field text and press enter

the line works:

```
ie.Document.all("ticker").innertext = "BBDCF230"
```

But just after, pressing enter, the webpage loads data from "BBDCF230" code into the others fields. I am trying to do this using :

```
Application.SendKeys "~" '## send the "Enter" keystroke
```

but its not working. Any Ideas?

```
Sub dxArray(ticker As String, ByRef premioEstimada() As truple, Optional mostrar As Boolean)
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

If mostrar = True Then
    ie.Visible = True
Else
    ie.Visible = False
End If

Application.StatusBar = "DX: " & ticker

ie.Navigate "https://opcoes.net.br/calculadora-Black-Scholes/" & ticker


    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'Equivalent = .ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'Wait 1 second, then check again.
    Loop

    ww1 = ie.Document.all("premioDaOpcao").Value

    For i = 0 To UBound(premioEstimada)

ie.Document.all("ticker").innertext = ""
ie.Document.all("ticker").innertext = "BBDCF230"
Application.SendKeys "~" '## send the "Enter" keystroke


ie.Document.all("cotacaoAcao").innertext = Replace(CStr(premioEstimada(i).cotacao), ".", ",")

ie.Document.all("btncalcular").Click

 Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Document.all("premioDaOpcao").Value = "" 'Equivalent = .ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'Wait 1 second, then check again.
 Loop

 premioEstimada(i).premioEstimado = ie.Document.all("premioDaOpcao").Value
 premioEstimada(i).ticker = ticker

 Next i

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing`enter code here`

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what is your issue. If you use `"https://opcoes.net.br/calculadora-Black-Scholes/" & ticker` you have what you want. The rest of your code has a lot of errors. Two examples: You cannot use `Sendkeys()` if IE is not visible and to set the value of an input text box you must use `Value` not `innerText`. But like I say, you only need the url with the ticker at it's end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps I was not clear in my post. Ok, I will make IE visible, this is not the problem. Okay, I'll use "value" instead of "innertext". The code I put in is a kind of draft. My main need is to fill the "ticker" field with different codes and trigger the "click enter" event without having to navigate directly to "https://opcoes.net.br/calculadora-Black-Scholes/ticker".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't understand what your macro is supposed to do, since I don't speak Portuguese. You use input parameters that I don't know where they come from and what they are good for.

Here is the technique to set the values automatically when the ticker value is changed. I am not a friend of Sendkeys(), but for this page I did not manage to get the values only via html events. You need both

**Here is a short macro to pass a ticker value to the macro to be called:**

```
Sub TickerTest()
  Call EnterTicker("BBDCF230")
End Sub
```

**This is the macro to enter the ticker and automatically set the corresponding values:**

```
Private Sub EnterTicker(ticker As String)

Const url As String = "https://opcoes.net.br/calculadora-Black-Scholes/"

Dim browser As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeInputTicker As Object

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'Manual break to complete the page code
  'The last three values are hours, minutes, seconds
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))

  'Shortening the html document reference
  Set htmlDoc = browser.document

  'Get the input textbox to enter the ticker value
  Set nodeInputTicker = htmlDoc.getElementByID("ticker")
  'Enter the ticker value
  nodeInputTicker.Value = ticker
  'Trigger the keypress html event of the ticker input textbox
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, nodeInputTicker, "keypress")
  'Send enter
  Application.SendKeys "~"
  'Wait to load the corresponding values
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
End Sub
```

**This is the procedure to trigger a html event**

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```